# Filter a table by id from JSON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

i would like to filter a table from a JSON Array in MySQL. Example:

```
select description from books where id_of_the_book in (jsonarray)
```

Actually i tried this:

```
set @test = JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('id','1'),JSON_OBJECT('id','2'),JSON_OBJECT('id','3'));

select description from books where id_of_the_book in (select JSON_EXTRACT(@test, '$**.id'))
```

but it wont work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

Using [13.5 Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html):

```sql
SET @`sql` := CONCAT('
SELECT
  `id`,
  `description`
FROM
  `books`
WHERE
  `id` IN (',
  (
    SELECT
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`, '$**.id'),
          ']',
          ''
        ),
        '[',
        ''
      )),
  ')');

PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`sql`;
EXECUTE `stmt`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
```

Using [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table):

```sql
SELECT
  `id`,
  `description`
FROM
  `books`
WHERE
  `id` IN (
    SELECT
      `der`.`_id_of_the_book`
    FROM
      JSON_TABLE(
        @`json`,
        '$[*]'
        COLUMNS(
          `_id_of_the_book` BIGINT UNSIGNED PATH '$.id'
        )
      ) `der`
    );
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ddf7761ab5d93d1fd7e16d754fc1894).

Comment: thank you, json table one could be the best, but my office is running mysql5.7. stmt one seems good in my case without the stored procedure!

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, found a solution

```
drop procedure if exists Sp_ConvertJsonToTable;
create procedure Sp_ConvertJsonToTable()
begin


 declare jsonTest json default JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('idcapitolo','1'),JSON_OBJECT('idcapitolo','2'),JSON_OBJECT('idcapitolo','3'));
 declare lunghezzaJson int default json_length(jsonTest);


declare contatore int default 0;


 drop temporary table if exists JsonToTableIds;
    create temporary table JsonToTableIds (
        valoriUtili int
    );




while contatore < lunghezzaJson do

    set @JsonSearch = concat('$[',contatore,'].idcapitolo');
    insert into JsonToTableIds(valoriUtili) values ((select json_unquote(json_extract(jsonTest,@JsonSearch))));
    set contatore = contatore + 1;
    end while;




-- select * from JsonToTableIds;
select descrizionebreve from capitolo where idcapitolo in((select * from JsonToTableIds));
drop temporary table JsonToTableIds;


end;
```